# XSLT assistance - repeating data (Part 2)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation, repeat

I've asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569768/xslt-assistance-repeating-data) which was resolved.

However I have found that I am also facing an issue where the data appears as below, instead of having the header values contained in an XML tag.

```
<results>
<body>
<line>
  <a>Column 1 Customer Name</a>
  <a>Column 2 Customer Add</a>
  <a>Column3</a>
  <a>Column4</a>
</line>
<line>
    <a>Data1</a>
    <a>Data2</a>
    <a>Data3</a>
    <a>Data4</a>
</line>
<line>
    <a>Data1</a>
    <a>Data2</a>
    <a>Data3</a>
    <a>Data4</a>
</line>
</body>
</results>
```

I've managed to find a method (external to XSLT) to distinguish between the two types, but need to achieve the same results, as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results>
<header>
<a>Column 1 Customer Name</a>
<a>Column 2 Customer Add</a>
<a>Column3</a>
<a>Column4</a>
</header>
<body>
<line>
    <Column1CustomerName>Data1</Column1CustomerName>
    <Column2CustomerAdd>Data2</Column2CustomerAdd>
    <Column3>Data3</Column3>
    <Column4>Data4</Column4>
</line>
<line>
    <Column1CustomerName>Data1</Column1CustomerName>
    <Column2CustomerAdd>Data2</Column2CustomerAdd>
    <Column3>Data3</Column3>
    <Column4>Data4</Column4>
</line>
</body>
</results>
```

The amount of lines can be unlimited, however the "headers" will always be the first line.
I have the theory on how I need to do this, by

```
<xsl:template match="/results/body/line[0]">
```

However that's about as far as I've got.

I was thinking it may be easier to complete a move of this data, to a tag "header" so I can execute the transformer as per the other question I asked, but do not know if this is a) the best approach, or b) possible?

As an additional question, would it be possible to put these two methods into a single XSLT?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNames" as="xs:string+" select=
     "/*/*/line[1]/a/translate(.,' ','')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <results>
    <header>
      <xsl:sequence select="/*/*/line[1]/a"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/line[position() ne 1]"/>
    </body>
   </results>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="line">
  <line>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
  </line>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:element name="{$vNames[$vPos]}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<results>
    <body>
        <line>
            <a>Column 1 Customer Name</a>
            <a>Column 2 Customer Add</a>
            <a>Column3</a>
            <a>Column4</a>
        </line>
        <line>
            <a>Data1</a>
            <a>Data2</a>
            <a>Data3</a>
            <a>Data4</a>
        </line>
        <line>
            <a>Data1</a>
            <a>Data2</a>
            <a>Data3</a>
            <a>Data4</a>
        </line>
    </body>
</results>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<results>
   <header>
      <a>Column 1 Customer Name</a>
      <a>Column 2 Customer Add</a>
      <a>Column3</a>
      <a>Column4</a>
   </header>
   <body>
      <line>
         <Column1CustomerName>Data1</Column1CustomerName>
         <Column2CustomerAdd>Data2</Column2CustomerAdd>
         <Column3>Data3</Column3>
         <Column4>Data4</Column4>
      </line>
      <line>
         <Column1CustomerName>Data1</Column1CustomerName>
         <Column2CustomerAdd>Data2</Column2CustomerAdd>
         <Column3>Data3</Column3>
         <Column4>Data4</Column4>
      </line>
   </body>
</results>
```